# OT Is Undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

While Calling `OT.initSession()` method of OpenTok I am getting

> OT is undefined.

I don't understand what is OT here.

```
  var session = OT.initSession(API_KEY, sessionId);
      session.on("sessionDisconnected", function(event) {
           console.log('The session disconnected. ' + event.reason);
       });
    const response = session.connect(sessionToken);
    console.log('response', response);
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in the first paragraph: What are you trying to achieve, what is your problem. Supply a working minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using webApi on node js (backend side).

If you see opentok.js -> https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js

```
exports.OT = t()
```

This is what OT is.
And initSession is directly a function on OT.

```
p.initSession = function(e, t, n) {
            return null == t && (t = e, e = null), 0 === g.value.length && e && (g.value = e, p.APIKEY = e), ge(e, t, n)
        };
```